# Apache Spark application deployment best practices

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a couple of use cases for Apache Spark applications/scripts, generally of the following form:

**General ETL use case** -
more specifically a transformation of a Cassandra column family containing many events (think event sourcing) into various aggregated column families.

**Streaming use case** -
realtime analysis of the events as they arrive in the system.

For **(1)**, I'll need to kick off the Spark application periodically.

For **(2)**, just kick off the long running Spark Streaming process at boot time and let it go.

*(Note - I'm using Spark Standalone as the cluster manager, so no yarn or mesos)*

I'm trying to figure out the most common / best practice deployment strategies for Spark applications.

So far the options I can see are:

1. **Deploying my program as a jar**, and running the various tasks with spark-submit - which seems to be the way recommended in the spark docs. Some thoughts about this strategy:

   - how do you start/stop tasks - just using simple bash scripts?
   - how is scheduling managed? - simply use cron?
   - any resilience? (e.g. Who schedules the jobs to run if the driver server dies?)
2. **Creating a separate webapp** as the driver program.

   - creates a spark context programmatically to talk to the spark cluster
   - allowing users to kick off tasks through the http interface
   - using Quartz (for example) to manage scheduling
   - could use cluster with zookeeper election for resilience
3. **Spark job server** (https://github.com/ooyala/spark-jobserver)

   - I don't think there's much benefit over (2) for me, as I don't (yet) have many teams and projects talking to Spark, and would still need some app to talk to job server anyway
   - no scheduling built in as far as I can see

I'd like to understand the general consensus w.r.t a simple but robust deployment strategy - I haven't been able to determine one by trawling the web, as of yet.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though you are not using Mesos for Spark, you could have a look at

-[Chronos](https://github.com/mesos/chronos)  offering a distributed and fault tolerant cron

-[Marathon](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon) a Mesos framework for long running applications

Note that this doesn't mean you have to move your spark deployment to mesos, e.g. you could just use chronos to trigger the spark -submit.

I hope I understood your problem correctly and this helps you a bit!

Comment: Thanks very much, Chronous does seem to do what I want, but I was hoping to stay away from having to deploy a Mesos cluster (I'd prefer to keep the infrastructure complexity small for what are some simple initial Spark use cases). Will have a closer look though - thanks!